# Android Studio 1.2.2 - Error "Select modules to import" importing google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, importerror

I'm trying to import **google-play-services_lib** into my Android aplication. 
I go to File > Project Structure > Modules > + > More Modules > Import Existing Project.
When I try to import it, I get the following error : **"Select modules to import"**

[Error Image](http://sia1.subirimagenes.net/img/2015/07/01/150701105345266258.png)

What I need to do ?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you are using gradle project, but if you do it is enough to add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` into `dependencies` in  `build.gradle` of you app module. More [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)